# How can I update the bootstrap theme by using sass?

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I would like to update my Django application theme by applying my customized theme to bootstrap.

Currently my static folder structure looks like this:

```
static
   bootstrap
       fonts
       js
       scss
         bootstrap.scss
   mytheme
       theme.scss
       _variables.scss
   main.scss
```

Whereas mytheme folder contains the style that override the style in bootstrap

I have a main.scss that will import the bootstrap.scss and mytheme scss file:

```
@import "/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "/mytheme/theme";
@import "/mytheme/variables";
```

When I run "python manage.py compress", I don't see the variable from mytheme folder override the content of the bootstrap.

If I put the files under mytheme into the bootstrap folder, everything works fine.

I am wondering if I can do with what I explain above? My goal is not to touch the bootstrap folder but to override the theme.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to load variables before your theme.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's one of the problem. I think I find out the root cause tho. The problem is that bootstrap/scss/bootstrap has a variable.scss which populate the actually css with the default theme. So when I import my scss files, it will be too late to override it. So I guess there is impossible to override the theme with my approach?